# Getting 'ads_connect: No logon servers' at irregular intervals

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, active-directory, samba

I'm currently setting up a Samba 4 AD server (on Ubuntu Server 16.04) with about 10 linux/windows members in planning. After successfully provisioning the domain controller I joined the first Xubuntu 16.04 client to the domain.

At first I was able to login at the client with a samba user account. So `wbinfo -u` and `getent passwd` both listed all samba accounts. A few minutes later I tried to log in again, but the logon screen only displayed the kerberos warning, that my password is about to expire in 41 days.

`getent passwd` now only lists the local users. `wbinfo -u` is inconsistently switching between an empty list and the samba users.

`net ads info -d 3` returns the following:

```
ads_connect: No logon servers
ads_connect: No logon servers
Didn't find the ldap server!
```

Deleting `/var/cache/samba/gencache.tdb` and `/var/run/samba/gencache_notrans.tdb` often changes the output to:

```
LDAP server: 10.230.44.1
LDAP server name: dc1.samdom.com # not the original domain
Realm: SAMDOM.COM
Bind Path: dc=SAMDOM,dc=COM
LDAP port: 389
Server time: Sa, 15 Okt 2016 18:01:33 CEST
KDC server: 10.230.44.1
Server time offset: 0
```

But after some time it is falling back to the output above. Sometimes simply waiting also does the trick.

I've got the same problem on a second client but not at the same time.

The server is inside a university network and also serves as a NAT router for the samba clients. However, it is possible for the clients to get internet access, if they use a non-private IP address.

`smb.conf` of the server:

```
[global] 
    workgroup = SAMDOM
    realm = SAMDOM.COM 
    netbios name = DC1
    server role = active directory domain controller 
    dns forwarder = xxx.yyy.xxx.yyy
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = Yes 

    # Only listen to the internal network 
    interfaces = eno2 
    bind interfaces only = Yes 

[netlogon] 
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/samdom.com/scripts 
    read only = No 

[sysvol] 
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol 
    read only = No
```

`smb.conf` on client:

```
[global] 
    netbios name = M1
    security = ADS
    workgroup = SAMDOM
    realm = SAMDOM

    log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log 
    log level = 1 

    # Default idmap config used for BUILTIN and local windows accounts/groups 
    idmap config *:backend = tdb 
    idmap config *:range = 2000-9999 

    # idmap config for domain SAMDOM 
    idmap config SAMDOM:backend = rid 
    idmap config SAMDOM:range = 10000-99999 

    # Use template settings for login shell and home directory 
    winbind nss info = template 
    template shell = /sbin/bash 
    template homedir = /home/%U 

    winbind enum users = Yes 
    winbind enum groups = Yes 
    winbind use default domain = Yes 
    encrypt passwords = Yes
```

The same setup without the server as NAT router but with normal IP addresses returns the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The client realm is `SAMDOM` instead of `SAMDOM.COM`.
It looks like typo in the question.
Also the DC interfaces ought to include the localhost interface `lo`.
The `net ads info` output is not debug enabled with `-d 3` as told.

The client and server realms have to match (and should resolve to a DNS domain). `net ads info` attempts to resolve DNS various domain names, including:

```
_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.<your realm>
_kerberos._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.<your realm>
```

otherwise it falls back to netbios name resolution on `<your workgroup>#1c`.

If I delete the caches, the `<your workgroup>#1c` entry is resolved with the ip of the DC valid for 660 seconds.
Else the `<your workgroup>#1c` value is discarded as its timeout is negative ( equal to `0 - <seconds since epoch>`).
The 660 seconds timeout is the `NAMECACHETIMEOUT` value.

All in all this should get you a step further but not out of the `No logon server` error. Even if the server is resolved, the client will issue a CLDAP netlogon request which will fail.
You could check with:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -h <you server ip> -x -b '' -s base "(&(NtVer=\06\00\00\00)(DnsDomain=<your realm>))" NetLogon
```

There debug are missing to sort this out.
If it is intermittent, likely another DNS server has stale entries and at times the DC is queried for domain names , while at times the other DNS server is.

NB: `<your realm>`, `<your workgroup>` and `<your server ip>` are placeholders.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Your answer could benefit from more detail (See [answer]). Please edit it to explain how  your solution works/how it addresses the OPs question.